# How to keep my WebView running when user locks the screen?

Tags: java, android, webview, wakelock

I'm new here and I'm also new to android app developement.
I've created an very simple app that streams muscic from a webradio url in a WebView. 
It works totally fine when my phone is charging : music keeps playing for hours in background, even when I lock the screen. 
The problem is when it's not charging : after ~10 min, it stops playing and when I resume the app the webview seems to be frozen.

I've done some research and I know I could use a MediaPlayer Service but I'm not quite convinced as I've tried it, and it takes really too much time to prepare. I want something quick. 
Loading the url in a WebView would be what I want, just like when I load the same url in Chrome : the music keeps playing for hours even if I lock the screen, so I don't understand why it doesn't in my WebView.

I've implemented a WakeLock but I'm not sure if it's what I need. I don't need the screen to be on, I just need my WebView to keep running when the phone is locked. 
This is my MainActivity :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    boutonPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPause);
    boutonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    navigateur =(MediaWebView) findViewById(R.id.navigateur);

    boutonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
    boutonPause.setOnClickListener(this);

    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
    wakeLock.setReferenceCounted(true);
    wakeLock.acquire();

}


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonPlay) {
        navigateur.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = navigateur.getSettings();
        navigateur.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        navigateur.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                return true;
            }

        });

        navigateur.loadUrl("https://listen.radioking.com/radio/96031/stream/134656");
    }
    else {
        WebSettings webSettings = navigateur.getSettings();
        navigateur.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        navigateur.loadUrl("about:blank");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    wakeLock.release();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    System.out.println("pause");
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("resume");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    System.out.println("stop");
}
```

and I've put this in my manifest :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Thank you !

My phone is a Xiaomi Redmi Note 5